# WP URL Re-writing plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I am trying to integrate a few non-wordpress PHP pages into an existing Wordpress site. Ideally, I want to rewrite anything request that looks like this: 'domain.com/books/bookname' to 'domain.com/catalog.php?title=bookname'. I have been messing around with the WP Rewrite API for several hours, but I just can't get anything to work. Here is my current plugin code:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'wbm_catalog_activate' );
function wbm_catalog_activate() {
    wbm_catalog_add_rules();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

// Flush when deactivated
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'wbm_catalog_deactivate' );
function wbm_catalog_deactivate() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

add_action( 'init', 'wbm_catalog_add_rules' );
function wbm_catalog_add_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'books/([^/]+)/?',
        'catalog.php?title=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}
```

I can even inspect the $wp_rewrite object and see my new rule added, but whenever I try to visit a rewritten url, wordpress acts as though the rule were not there.

I have been banging my head up against a brick wall, and I would appreciate any help you could give!

Comment: If you want an off-the-shelf solution, [Redirection](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) can do this. (I just used it to redirect a menu item pointing at `/forum/de` to the German translation of our phpBB forums at `/forum/index.php?rlang=de`, and it definitely supports regular expressions and back references.) Just make sure you turn off URL monitoring on its Options page; it can confuse the hell out of you if it auto-redirects things when they move, and it's on by default!

Comment: Isn't there some .htaccess settings you need to enable? I don't think Wordpress is capable of handling rewrites without telling apache to let you.

Comment: Matt, the Redirection plugin looks great, but it doesn't look like it has support for unobtrusive URL rewriting, just redirection. I'll take a look at it and see if I could modify it achieve the desired behaviour. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrew I believe that Redirection supports unobtrusive rewriting in its "htaccess" mode/group -- think it's called "pass-through" in there, though I've not played with it much. In that case, Redirection just acts as a relatively friendly interface to mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: @MattGibson, Thanks, I have been playing around with Redirection a little bit more, and I still can't get the "pass-through" to work. I am thinking that it may have something to do with a funky Wordpress Multisite install. Thank you for turning me onto the Redirection plugin - it is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to ever resolve this issue. The site that I was working on was part of an old WordPressMU setup (2.8) with a number of sites. I did not have access to the .htaccess that the MU install was using, and it was not passing any requests through to the .htaccess file that I could edit.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is:

The statement `flush_rewrite_rules` is executed before `add_rewrite_rule` and therefore the new cache generated does not include your stuffs in `add_rewrite_rule`.

You can verify with the value in your DB

```
select option_name, option_value from wp_options where option_name = 'rewrite_rules';
```